# Multiple drawings inside a drawing

Tags: java, android, graphics, view, drawing

I'm having a problem which I can't seem to solve. I need to make something like a doll. This doll will move its legs and his head (Kinda like a medical bed).

I though I could solve this by creating my own View class, like a DollView extending from View, then using the onDraw method to make the head, body, legs and the bed rectangle. The problem I found is that I can't really just make a circle, I need to specify a place where he should stay. I'd like just to say "draw a circle with this radius, draw the body and legs to the right side of the head, and the bed rectangle below them". Then I'd like to set their position in the XML layout, where they would be moved as a group. But they would be manipulated individually (like setting the legs angle).

So I though about creating like the DollView. I'm guessing here I'll need inner classes (Head, Legs, Bed, Body) so I can manipulate them and their angles. But I'm still very lost, and I really need help. So thank you in advance.

EDIT: After thinking more, I guess I don't really need all those inner classes. I could just use parameters on the DollView or DollLayout to store the head, body and legs angles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See this example http://atstechlab.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/gauge-widget-available-at-google-code/. 
In it picture build from separated bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a DollLayout not a DollView, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) article about layouts, it will help you.

Comment: Yeh well, I understand that, but ViewGroups aren't supposed to be used so I can group another Views in it? Which is not exactly what I need to do. I mean, yeh, I need to draw things and put them all together and manipulate individually. Still, that would be very specific, and as far as I understand by reading the articles, a ViewGroup would be to group any kind of Views.